# ADF Dataflow stuck IN progress and fail with below errors

Tags: azure-data-factory

ADF Pipeline DF task is Stuck in Progress. It was working seamlessly last couple of months but suddenly Dataflow stuck in progress and Time out after certain time. We are using IR managed Virtual Network. I am using forereach loop to run data flow for multiple entities parallel, it always randomly get stuck on last Entity.

What can I try to resolve this?

Error in Dev Environment

```
Error Code 4508
Spark cluster not found
```

Error in Prod Environment:

```
Error code
5000
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
[plugins.*** ADF.adf-ir-001 WorkspaceType:<ADF> CCID:<f289c067-7c6c-4b49-b0db-783e842a5675>] [Monitoring] Livy Endpoint=[https://hubservice1.eastus.azuresynapse.net:8001/api/v1.0/publish/815b62a1-7b45-4fe1-86f4-ae4b56014311]. Livy Id=[0] Job failed during run time with state=[dead].
```

Images:

[image]

[image]

I tried below steps:

1. By changing IR configuring as below

[image]

2. Tried DF Retry and retry Interval

[image]

3. Also, tried For each loop one batch at a time instead of 4 batch parallel. None of the above trouble-shooting steps worked. These PL is running last 3-4 months without a single failure, suddenly they started to fail last 3 days consistently. DF flow always stuck in progress randomly for different entity and times out in one point by throwing above errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Error Code 4508 Spark cluster not found.

This error can cause because of two reasons.

- The debug session is getting closed till the dataflow finish its transformation in this case recommendation is to restart the debug session
  [image]
- the second reason is due to resource problem, or an outage in that particular region.

> Error code 5000 Failure type User configuration issue Details [plugins.*** ADF.adf-ir-001 WorkspaceType: CCID:] [Monitoring] Livy Endpoint=[https://hubservice1.eastus.azuresynapse.net:8001/api/v1.0/publish/815b62a1-7b45-4fe1-86f4-ae4b56014311]. Livy Id=[0] Job failed during run time with state=[dead].

- A temporary error is one that says "Livy job state dead caused by unknown error." At the backend of the dataflow, a spark cluster is used, and this error is generated by the spark cluster. to get the more information about error go to `StdOut` of sparkpool execution.
- The backend cluster may be experiencing a network problem, a resource problem, or an outage.

If error persist my suggestion is to raise Microsoft support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket)